# Как загрузить фото в Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Пытаюсь загрузить изображение на сайт с помощью:

```
element.sendKeys(photo.getAbsolutePath());
```

Но этот элемент на сайте хранится в `div` у которого есть параметр:

```
overflow`: `hidden`
```

Слышал, что можно обнаружить элемент с помощью `JavaScript`, но не нашел подходящего решения.

Comment: Я конечно не знаю, но слышал что Selenium Webdriver не умеет загружать данные. Может и ошибаюсь, ждем более опытных людей

Comment: Нашёл ответ :)
Нужно выполнить следующий скрипт JS внутри метода
String js = "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';";
    executeJavaScript(js, element);
    element.sendKeys(photo.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Вы можете добавить ответ в качестве своего ответа)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно выполнить следующий скрипт JS внутри метода String js = "arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';"; executeJavaScript(js, element); element.sendKeys(photo.getAbsolutePath());